# Reheating mongodb without using touch command

Tags: mongodb, caching, mongodb-query

I'm trying to do cache reheating in mongodb without using **touch** command.Currently i'm running a script that does a **find** query and iterate using the **cursor** , doing so mongodb automatically loads pages into memory. But this script takes a lot of time to complete.

So in search of better solution , I found an article [link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/cache-reheating-not-to-be-ignored) that tells the basic of cache reheating in which there is suggestion that says

**One could just sequentially read data in and fill the cache.**

I was not able to figure out, how one can do that using /dev/null on ubuntu?Any suggestions

Thanks in advance

Comment: The link you provided is really old, and outdated.  It makes references to the (now removed) storage engine MMAPv1 and its capabilities around sequential reads from disk.

Comment: which means we don't have any good optimization for reheating the collection

Comment: Consider the concept of cache - it keeps recently used items in memory under the assumption it is likely you will attempt to request these same items.  It uses history to predict future use.  Since you rebooted your system there is no history.  MongoDB does not keep usage statistics (not yet anyways) so there is no way to know what should be loaded into cache.  If your entire database fits in memory then the concept of cache no longer applies and instead you have in-memory database (which is very fast but expensive).  You could make assumptions that recently created docs should be loaded...